# Using Python to upload document to Dropbox API with Flask

Tags: python, flask, dropbox-api

Attempting to upload a document through Dropbox's API through a `Submit` button on Flask application. The HTML loads on localhost, but whenever I upload the document and hit `Sumbit`, there is a `404` error and the document does not post to the Dropbox API. Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

### Python

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import dropbox

# Function Definition
def uploader(token, file):
   target = '/temp'
   targetFile = target + 'test.docx'
   connection = dropbox.Dropbox(token)
   meta = connection.files_upload(file, targetFile, mode=dropbox.files.WriteMode("overwrite"))

# Flask App
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def upload_document():
    if request.method == "POST":
        uploader(token, request.files['file'])
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
        <body>
            <form method = "post" action = "/home" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
                <p>
                    <input type="file" name="file" autocomplete="off" required>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </p>
            </form> 
        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue stemmed from the script not reading the file when being passed through the function via the Dropbox connection. When using this, add `file.read()` within the connection.

```
# Function Definition
def uploader(token, file):
   target = '/temp'
   targetFile = target + 'test.docx'
   connection = dropbox.Dropbox(token)
   meta = connection.files_upload(file.read(), targetFile, mode=dropbox.files.WriteMode("overwrite"))
```